# Transversality in stochastic control

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-analysis, control-theory, optimal-control

This question is about transversality condition in a stochastic control problem.

**Transversality condition**

Consider an infinite horizon stochastic control problem

$$ 
\sup_{u(\cdot) \in \mathcal{A}} E^x\Big[\int_0^{\infty} f(X^u_t, u_t) dt\Big]
$$

where the state $X$ follows a controlled SDE

$$
dX^u = \mu(X, u) dt + \sigma(X, u) dB, \; X_0 = x.
$$

The class of admissible controls is defined by (suppressing appropriate measurability assumptions)

$$
\mathcal{A} = \{ u(\cdot) | E[\int_0 ^{\infty} |f(X^u_t, u_t)| dt ] < \infty  \}.
$$

The variational inequality is

$$
\max_u f -\rho V + \mu V_x + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 V_xx = 0.
$$

If a function $V$ solves the HJB equation with corresponding $u^*$, then we have the following verification theorem-type statement for sufficiency: If the following two conditions hold for all $x$

$$
1. \;\; \liminf_{t \rightarrow \infty} e^{- \rho t} E^x[V(X_t^{u^*})] \geq 0 , \;\; \mbox{transversality condition}\\
2. \;\; E^x[\int_0^{\infty} |V_x(X_t^{u^*}) \sigma(X_t^{u^*}, u^*)|^2] < \infty, \;\;\mbox{martingale condition}
$$

then $u^*$ is an optimal control.

This can be argued as follows: for all $t > 0, x$ and $u(\cdot) \in \mathcal{A}$,

\begin{align*}
V(x) &= e^{-\rho t} V(X^{u^*}_t) + \int_0^t e^{-\rho s} [\rho  V(X^{u^*}_s) -  \mu(X^{u^*}_s, u^*_s) V_x(X^{u^*}_s)) - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2(X^{u^*}_s, u^*_s) V_{xx} (X^{u^*}_s] ds - \int_0 ^t V_x(X^{u^*}_s) \sigma dB \\
     &\geq e^{-\rho t} V(X^{u^*}_t) + \int_0^t e^{-\rho t} f(X^{u}_s, u_s) ds - \int_0 ^t V_x(X^{u^*}_s) \sigma(X^{u^*}_s, u_s) dB \\
\end{align*}

Taking expectation on both sides gives
\begin{align*}
V(x) &\geq e^{-\rho t}  E^x [ V(X^{u^*}_t)] +  E^x [ \int_0^t e^{-\rho t} f(X^{u}_s, u_s) ds] -  E^x [\int_0^t V_x(X^{u^*}_s) \sigma(X^{u^*}_s, u_s) dB] \\
\end{align*}

Taking the limit as $t \rightarrow \infty$,

**(i)** $e^{-\rho t}  E^{x} [ V(X^{u^*}_t)]$ vanishes by the transversality condition.

**(ii)** $E^{x} [\int_0^t V_x \sigma dB] = 0$ for all $t$ by the martingale condition.

**(iii)** $E^{x} [ \int_0^t e^{-\rho t} f(X^{u}_s, u_s) ds]$ converges to
$E^{x} [ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\rho t} f(X^{u}_s, u^*_s) ds]$
by definition of admissibility and the dominated convergence theorem.
Therefore $u^*$ is optimal.

**A specific problem**

$$
\max_{c, \psi} E^x[\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\rho s} (-e^{\gamma c_s}) ds ]
$$

where the state evolves according to

$dX = (rX - c + \psi(\mu - r)) dt + \psi \sigma dB$.

Solving the HJB equation gives feedback/Markov control

\begin{align*}
c(x) &= rx - \frac{1}{\gamma r}(r - \rho - \frac{1}{2} \frac{(\mu-r)^2}{\sigma^2}) \\
     &\equiv rx - D,
\end{align*}

$$
\psi(x) = \frac{\mu - r}{\sigma^2 r \gamma} \equiv E.
$$

Now these solutions satisfy the above conditions for verification:

\begin{align*}
dX^{u^*} &= (D + E(\mu -r)) dt + E \sigma dB \\
         &\equiv F dt + G dB.
\end{align*}

So $E[V(X^{u^*}_t)] = - e^{(F + \frac{1}{2} G^2)t}$ and the transversality condition holds under some restrictions on the parameters $(r, \mu,\sigma, \rho, \gamma)$.
Similarly, $E[V_x(X^{u^*}_t)] = -e^{(r \gamma F + \frac{1}{2} r^2 \gamma^2 G^2)t}$ and the martingale condition holds
under some restrictions on the parameters.

**Question**

In general one would like to interpret the transversality condition (in the form, say, $\lim e^{- \rho t} E^x [V(X^{u^*}_t)] = 0$) as "leaving no money on the table". 
The general argument seems to hold regardless of the sign of $f$.
But something seems strange when the instantaneous utility $f$ is negative.
In the specific problem above,
$0$ in this case should be interpreted formally as
infinity, and the transversality condition would say that $e^{- \rho t} E^x [V(X^{u^*}_t)]$ is infinity in the limit, which seems strange. Anyone have a interpretation/comments on this?

Comment: It seems that this has to do with the fact that the discount factor $e^{- \rho t}$ does the opposite of discounting when utility is negative.